# GNU backup without server software

Tags: backup

At work, I had been provided a network folder to do backups, so I'm looking for some software (to be run under Windows 10 32b/64b) to do the backups.

- It needs a GUI interface (no command line)
- It shouldn't require software installed on the server
- Preferably GNU
- Stored file formats should be in common known formats (zip, tar)
- Should be able to do incremental and differential backup
- Should atomatically do the backups periodically

I had been checking Amanda anb Bacula, but they seem to require software installed on the server, and I only have a network folder. I do not control the servers.

Comment: Welcome aboard. You might want to add the [tag:gratis] tag, if you want something free - or state a budget. If free, you might also state that the license should be free for commercial use, as many solutions are free only for home use.

Comment: Your best bet may actually be to use scheduled tasks to achieve this.  Alternatively, if you can tolerate the backup consisting of the files themselves instead of actual archive files, you may want to look into the File History feature that's built into Windows 10.

Comment: Scheduled tasks and robocopy should be ample, but tools such as DSycnrinize and Cobian will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our IT department has set up [Personal Backup](http://personal-backup.rathlev-home.de/index-e.html) for this purpose.

- our whole company uses it at work, so that should fit your needs.
- it has [a GUI](http://personal-backup.rathlev-home.de/images/pb-en.png) to set up the backup, e.g. the folders to be included and excluded. Well, GUI and usability sometimes are two different things. See some examples below.
- it can store in ZIP or GZ archives (I can't confirm GZ, although that's mentioned in the feature list)
- it supports incremental and differential backup (see German screenshot below)
- it can perform backups automatically by itself (thus it will run at startup) or via Windows task scheduler
- it does not need server-side software. You just need a network share (e.g. mapped drive or something like `\\server\share`)
- [it's gratis](http://personal-backup.rathlev-home.de/license-e.html), so it will fit your budget.

[image: Incremental and differential]

It worked well for ~ 2 years now. Unfortunately, I lost the backup configuration (not the backup itself) once. It's unclear whether this was related to an update issue by Personal Backup or some file corruption on my disk.

The software is still maintained and you'll be notified about updates.

Things I don't like regarding usability:

- you can't delete a backup configuration if it's currently open.
- you can't close a backup configuration, so you can never delete the last backup configuration.
- you can only have 16 different automatic backups
- it does not have tabs and it's not possible to start 2 instances of it, so it's very hard to compare 2 backup configurations